# Avoid duplication of code when specializing a generic

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method which look something like this:

```cs
void Foo<A, B>()
{
    // Do some stuff with B, some  conditionals, etc, e.g.:
    using (var scope = _provider.CreateScope())
    {
        var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<B>();
        A result = service.Bar<A>();
    }
    // Do some more stuff with B
}
```

Now I'd like to use a second specialized version of `Bar` which has a different return type, something like the following:

```cs
void Foo<A, B>() where A : List<A>
{
    // Do the exact same stuff with B
    List<A> result = service.Bar2<A>();
    // Do other same stuff with B
}
```

The `Bar` methods might look something like:

```cs
A Bar<A>()
{
    return new A();
}

List<A> Bar2<A>()
{
    return new List<A>();
}
```

Is there something I can do without having all of the duplicated code surrounding the `Bar` calls? Can I use something like a `Func` as a parameter? Should I give up on using generics here and try to using polymorphism?

Comment: Could you please share an examples of `Outer<A>` and `Bar`/`Bar2` methods?

Comment: Can you show some examples of the code that are duplicated? Just so that I can put the question into context more easily.

Comment: @Pavel, I changed Outer to List, for something more specific.

Comment: @Sweeper I added some more context - hope it doesn't confuse things.

Comment: Oh I see, so instead of lambdas taking in _values_, you want lambdas that takes _types_. I don't think C# has those. You can try it with reflection, but I think that's worse than code duplication.

Comment: Does `Bar` also have an overload that takes a `Type`? Many methods in the .NET framework that needs a type usually have two overloads - one that takes the type as a generic type, and one that takes it as a `Type` object. Does `Bar` have something similar?

Comment: Could you give an example of this? I'm not exactly sure what you mean?

Comment: (You didn't @ me, so I didn't get a notification... Sorry for the delay) Anyway, I can't think of an example in the .NET framework right now. But if you look at [`JsonConvert.DeserialiseObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) or Unity's [EntityManager.HasComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.0/api/Unity.Entities.EntityManager.html#Unity_Entities_EntityManager_HasComponent_Unity_Entities_Entity_Unity_Entities_ComponentType_), you'll see there're overloads taking a `Type`, and also generic ones.